# Is it possible to use the iPhone camera inside an iAd?

Tags: ios, iad

Is it possible to access the camera inside an iAd?

I readed that the language to create iAds is JS so I believe that it can't be accesed. But there is not so many docs about iAd.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there is a way of doing it. I advise you to download the iAd Producer. Once you install it, there is an "extra" directory in the .dmg disk. There are some useful examples, one of them is the access of the camera and images manipulation.

https://developer.apple.com/iad/iadproducer/

In any case, this is a small snippet for a button that will trigger the camera and will show the taken picture in an image view:

```
var button = this.viewController.outlets.button;
```

var image = this.viewController.outlets.image;

this.onViewTouchUpInside = function (event) {

```
// Access the camera object
var camera = window.ad.camera;

// if the API is unavailable, the object will be null
if (!camera) {
    if (iAd.Device.iOSVersionLessThan('5.0')) {
        alert('The Camera API is not available in iOS ' + iAd.Device.iOS_VERSION);
    }
    else {
        alert('The Camera API could not be accessed.');
    }

    return;
}

// Reason from the app to explain the user
var reason = 'The app would like to take a photo';
camera.present(reason);
```

};

if (window.ADCamera) {

```
this.viewController.addEventListener(ADCamera.ADCameraUserTookPicture, function (event) {

    // access the camera object
    var camera = window.ad.camera; 

    // access the new picture
    var newPicture = camera.currentPictureURI;

    // set the image view's image to the new picture
    image.image = new iAd.Image(newPicture);         


}, false);


this.viewController.addEventListener(ADCamera.ADCameraUserCanceledPicture, function (event) {
}, false);
```

}

Good luck!